# How to solve when user leaves some tags or quotes open in source of CKeditor?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am inserting data in MySQL with CKeditor and PHP. I am taking raw HTML from the user side. If the user leaves some quotes or tags open then how could I handle this problem?

For example, if users inputs in source of ckeditor and leaves quotes open, then how to solve this in PHP?

```
<p style="color:red;> Some Content </p>
```

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnTic.png)

And the HTML string is save in `$postObj->post_content`.

I am getting this error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given on line 55 and here is my code ... libxml_use_internal_errors(true); $dom = new DOMDocument(); $dom->loadHtml($postObj->post_content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); $cont = $dom->saveHTML().PHP_EOL; $res = $common->findFirstPara($cont,$ad_content); libxml_clear_errors();

Comment: Pass it though domdocument, https://3v4l.org/bEWQO then it will render the broken bits htmlentities, so your outer DOM is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I try this code in my site. It gave me error.

Comment: What error did it give?

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given on line 55 and here is my code ...
                  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                  $dom = new DOMDocument();

                  $dom->loadHtml($postObj->post_content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

                  $cont = $dom->saveHTML().PHP_EOL;

                $res = $common->findFirstPara($cont,$ad_content); 

                libxml_clear_errors();

Comment: It still gives the same error:                                                                      
                                                                                                                 Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given on line 42

Comment: Update your question with the code your using.

Comment: i have updated my question...

Comment: No you have removed everything.. I want to see the PHP code not the string your passing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It is not compatible with screen-readers, search-engines and clipboard, and as such makes it harder for people to help you. Please replace it with code as text, in a formatted block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tidy](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)

```
$html = '<p style="color:red;> Some Content </p>';
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html);
$tidy->cleanRepair();
return $tidy;
```

Comment: It gives an error---  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$tidy' (T_VARIABLE) on line 38

Comment: Line no. 38 is--- $tidy = tidy_parse_string($html);